# How can I add an external tool to Visual Studio with a script or similar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, configuration, cmd, external-tools

We want to deploy some external tools to Visual Studio for our developers. Is there a way to automate it through a script or similar or should all of them do it manually?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2013, the external tools are managed in the registry at

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\External Tools

[image]

You should be able to write a registry script to add what you need.  Make sure to backup the registry before any updating.

Comment: Ops ... it requires some intelligence as it has to check how many tools are already added ... too complex for a busy man ... manual instructions :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I stumbled upon this question while looking for the same thing, and ended up writing a batch file that identifies new available tool number.

Set desired VS versions comma separated (works up to VS 2015 - 14.0, VS 2017 uses private registry - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-rc-store-its-config)) , and the parameters for the tool in the beginning of the file.

```vb
@echo off
echo.
rem ========================================
rem Configure desired Tool values and desired VS Versions (tested only for 14.0, other should be the same)
rem ========================================

set VSVersions=13.0,14.0

set ToolTitle=Abrir prompt testes front-end...
set ToolCmd=$(SolutionDir)\FrontendTestsPrepare.bat
set ToolDir=$(SolutionDir)
set ToolOpt=0x12
set ToolArg=
set ToolSourceKey=





rem ========================================
rem Logic begins
rem ========================================


for %%a in ("%VSVersions:,=" "%") do (
    CALL:REGISTER_TOOL %%~a
)

exit /b



:REGISTER_TOOL
set VSToolRegKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\%1\External Tools
echo Registering tool for VS %1

rem ========================================
rem Gets and sets tool count and new index
rem ========================================

CALL:GETTOOLCOUNT "%VSToolRegKey%"
set ToolCount=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo Tool Index: %ToolCount%
set NewToolIndex=%ToolCount%
set /a NewToolCount=%ToolCount%+1

rem ========================================
rem Update Tool Count
rem ========================================
reg add "%VSToolRegKey%" /v ToolNumKeys /f /t REG_DWORD /d 0x%NewToolCount%

rem ========================================
rem Creates 
rem ========================================
reg add "%VSToolRegKey%" /v ToolTitle%NewToolIndex% /d "%ToolTitle%"
reg add "%VSToolRegKey%" /v ToolCmd%NewToolIndex% /d "%ToolCmd%"
reg add "%VSToolRegKey%" /v ToolDir%NewToolIndex% /d "%ToolDir%"
reg add "%VSToolRegKey%" /v ToolOpt%NewToolIndex% /d %ToolOpt% /t REG_DWORD
reg add "%VSToolRegKey%" /v ToolArg%NewToolIndex% /d "%ToolArg%"
reg add "%VSToolRegKey%" /v ToolSourceKey%NewToolIndex% /d "%ToolSourceKey%"

echo.
echo.

GOTO :EOF




:GETTOOLCOUNT
set ToolCount=0
set RegQueryOutput=

rem Tests if registry path exists, returning 1 if not
reg query %1 /f ToolNumKeys /v > nul 2>&1

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 exit /b %ToolCount%

rem Gets tool count from reg query output
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('reg query %1 /f ToolNumKeys /v ^| findstr "0x.*"') do set RegQueryOutput=%%i
for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%E in ("%RegQueryOutput%") do set ToolCount=%%E
set ToolCount=%ToolCount:0x=%

exit /b %ToolCount%
```

The flags that can be or'ed together in "ToolOpt" are the following (extracted from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3ad7480-fb6d-4c9a-96be-44e32141c461/programmatically-add-external-tools?forum=vsx)):

```
#define TOOLOPT_ISAPPGUI      0x01
#define TOOLOPT_CLOSEONEXIT   0x02
#define TOOLOPT_PROMPTFORARGS 0x04
#define TOOLOPT_USEOUTPUTWIN  0x08
#define TOOLOPT_SAVEALLDOCS   0x10
#define TOOLOPT_USETASKLIST   0x20
#define TOOLOPT_UNICODE       0x40
```